# Exception expected syntax error

Tags: java

```
private void do somthing(Field [] input){

final Class [] CLASSES = {someButton,someTextPanel}
}
```

someButton и someTextPanel подчеркнуты красным, компилятор говорит: "Exception expected"

Как правильно это написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final Class [] CLASSES = {someButton.class,someTextPanel.class} }`

Comment: Либо экземпляр класса, разумеется...

{new someButton(), new someTextPanel()}

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я затупил